# How to create dynamic HTTP request path

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-api, httprequest

I have a basic app in Vue.js where I am using Google Drive/Docs API via vue-google-api plugin [link here](https://github.com/vertcitron/vue-google-api).

I have a method **execute()** as in code snippet below. The first POST request is making a copy of existing document. The second POST is about to replace few words in copied file.

**response.result.id** returns correct documentId of copied file.

I would like to use that ID as part of PATH for second POST request but I cannot figure out how to achieve that.

Any help would be great, thanks.

```
execute() {
    this.$gapi
        .request({
          path:
            "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1xTvsBoqCiKE5XfSRklRPBWMbkCtdJSnzGEdT7B76TZM/copy",
          method: "POST"
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            let documentId = response.result.id;
            let imieUcznia = "Alice";
            let requests = [
                {
                    replaceAllText: {
                        containsText: {
                            text: "{{imieUcznia}}",
                            matchCase: true
                        },
                        replaceText: imieUcznia
                    }
              }
          ];
          this.$gapi
              .request({
                  path: "https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/${documentId}:batchUpdate",
                  method: "POST",
                  body: {
                      requests
                  }
              })
              .then(response => {
                  console.log(response);
              });
        });
},
```

Comment: template strings use ` not "

Comment: Great thanks to all of you guys, so easy and so useful...of course, it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the ` symbol to use template strings

```
execute() {
      this.$gapi
        .request({
          path:
            "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1xTvsBoqCiKE5XfSRklRPBWMbkCtdJSnzGEdT7B76TZM/copy",
          method: "POST"
        })
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response);
          let documentId = response.result.id;

          let imieUcznia = "Alice";
          let requests = [
            {
              replaceAllText: {
                containsText: {
                  text: "{{imieUcznia}}",
                  matchCase: true
                },
                replaceText: imieUcznia
              }
            }
          ];
          this.$gapi
            .request({
              path:
                `https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/${documentId}:batchUpdate`, // <-- here
              method: "POST",
              body: {
                requests
              }
            })
            .then(response => {
              console.log(response);
            });
        });
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Javascript Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) ie use ` instead of "

```
path: `https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/${documentId}:batchUpdate`,
//    ^ Observe here
```